# php: get the word coordinates (sentence num, word num) by position of character in the string

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I'm curious of the question about the performance.

There is a php string `$text` that contains English text of several sentences. To simplify the problem, let's guess each sentence finishes with "." always, and there are no other symbols like , ? ! etc. in the text.

```
$sentences = array();
$sentences = explode(". ",  $text);//we split the text into array of sentences

$words = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($sentences); $i++){
   $words[$i] = explode(" ",  $sentences[$i]);//split each sentence into words
}
```

So, the `$words` is a two-dimensional array.

`$words[$i][$j]` is the word #j in the sentence #i. Right?

The question is:

what's **the fastest** way to find the word coordinates by the position of the letter in the string?

So, if we have the text:

```
I go to school. And you.


$word = positionFinder(0);//I  $word == array(0,0)  - the zero word in the zero sentence
$word = positionFinder(1);//' ' $word == array(-1," ")  or something like that
$word = positionFinder(6);//to $word == array(0,2)
$word = positionFinder(9);//school $word == array(0,3)
$word = positionFinder(10);//school $word == array(0,3)
$word = positionFinder(14);//. $word == array (-1,".") or something like that
$word = positionFinder(17);//And $word == array(1,0) - the zero word in the first sentence
```

I believe for better performance some data in an additional array could be used. The `positionFinder` function will be used more times than the number of words in the text. So the `positionFinder` should work as fast as possible.

So it is kind of finding the word coordinates by its letter.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) can also give you the position of a word.

Comment: Could you please explain how to get an array(1,0) (the 1st sentence, zero word position) by passing 17 as a parameter (17 is the letter A of the word And) to the function positionFinder(17) using strpos? Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you asked ?

Comment: `$str = 'I go to school. And you.';echo strpos($str, 'A');` will return you `16`, position of `A`.

Comment: I need by entering 16 it returns this answer: the first word of the second sentence, the word "And". 
So, it returns the array that contains two numbers in it: array(1, 0) (2 because of the second (sentence), 1 because of the first word). The answer contains (sentence #, the word in the sentence #). Did I explain it clear? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
function positionFinder($text, $n) {
    $s=$text[$n];
    $i=0;
    $sep = array(" ", ".")
    while (!in_array($text[$n-$i],$sep)) {
        $s = $text[$n+$i].$s;
        $i++;
    }
    $i=1
    while (!in_array($text[$n+$i],$sep)) {
        $s .= $text[$n+$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

But would be faster if you create a "positionFinder" array like:

```
function makearray($text) {
    $sentences = explode(". ",  $text);
    $positionFinder = array();
    $slen = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($sentences); $i++) {
       $words[$i] = explode(" ",  $sentences[$i]);
       for ($ii=0; $ii<count($words[$i]); $ii++) {
           $positionFinder[$slen] = $words[$i][$ii];
           $slen += strlen($words[$i])+1; //+1 because of " "
       }
       $slen+=strlen($sentences[$i])+2; //+2 because of ". "
    }
    return $positionFinder;
}
```

I will take a while to make the array but then it would be very fast to check it:

```
$text="I go to school. And you. ";
$positionFinder = makearray($text);
echo $positionFinder[0];
>>  I
echo $positionFinder[2];
>>  go
...
```